# I want to make a picklist field required in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, picklist, salesforcedx

```
<div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_edit  slds-form-element_stacked slds-hint-parent">
<c:PicklistSelect objectName="Events__c" fieldName="CurrencyIsoCode" label="Currency" value="{!v.eventObject.CurrencyIsoCode}"/>
 </div>
```

Hey this is the code.. Here the PicklistSelect is a component and this is a currency field in a lightning component. How can i make this field required?

Is there any workaround?

Comment: You need to provide more info what code is there in `c:PicklistSelect ` component.

Comment: You can use required attribute here or handle it in aura handler. Please provide more details on your picklist component.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the underlying code of your custom  component `c:PicklistSelect` its hard to tell if you can go down the easy path (as mentioned in the comments and previous answer) normally, if using the [lightning:Select](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/example) component, there is a required attribute, otherwise, you will have to add validation in your client side controller to ensure that the field is populated (or any other validation).

you can check [w3schools - JavaScript Forms](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) for sample valdiation which you could adapt to your needs:

```
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value; /
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```